# Query to get first time customers per week

Tags: database

how can I get the number of new/first time customers per week from my magento store with an SQL query?

Does somebody knows that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to retrieve customers which accounts are no older than 7 days, right?

If this is it, it's a pretty easy SQL Query.
Something like this can do the job:

```
SELECT * 
FROM customer_entity
WHERE (
`created_at` > DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 7 
DAY )
)
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Ofcourse then you receive whole records, not just the count of new customers.

If you'd like to retrieve just the count of them use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customer_entity WHERE (`created_at` > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 365 DAY));
```

Here's a great answer from another question how timestamp queries should be done:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17198760/4022683

Comment: Hey @versedi thanks for the quick response. Can I also group them by week, so that I can create a visualization like "Calendar Week 30: 7 customers, Calendar Week 31: 10 customer" ?

Comment: Sure, this would take some time to prepare but you could create a simple function where you'd pass the time-interval as parameter. 

You can extract number of week using this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18400181/4022683